# GetExtendedTcpTable in Windows 2000

Tags: c++, mfc, tcp, pid, windows-2000

Which mechanism can I use to get all open ports with the associated PID's (process ID's) in Windows 2000?

GetExtendedTcpTable is not available and the same problem with the console command netstat -ao (option -o not on-hand)!

Thank you in advance!

greets leon22

Answer (score 0):

I also have found this hotfix to get the `netstat -o` option on Windows 2000 (but I don't know if it's allowed to install this fix on the company PC)!

Link: http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=907980&kbln=de

It would be better if anyone know an other option?!

Answer (score 0):

I found this post useful: http://forum.sysinternals.com/socket-handles_topic1193.html

The example code works quiet happily under windows 2000 professional